# Invalid alias when joining two JPA entities via JPA 2.0 CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two JPA entities

```
class A{
    @OneToMany
    Lis<B> entitiesB;
    @Column("STATUS")
    String status;// will sort based on this column
}
```

and

```
class B{
    @ManyToOne
    A entityA;
    @Column("PROPERTY_ONE")
    String propertyOne;
    ....
    @Column("PROPERTY_M")
    String propertyM;
    ....
}
```

I need to left join A with B and then perform filtering on columns from B. I have the following criteria:

```
Join<A, B>root=criteriaBuilder
.createQuery(A.class)
.from(A.class)
.join("entitiesB");

CriteriaQuery<A> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(A.class);

query.select(query.from(A.class).join("entitiesB"))
        .distinct(true)
        .where(formWhereClause(filters))
        .orderBy(formOrderByClause());
```

How do I form the filter by the `status` property from `A` entity

```
criteriaBuilder.notEqual(root.get("A").get("status"), "SOME_STATUS_VALUE");
```

It has generated me the following SQL:

```
select distinct generatedAlias0 from A as generatedAlias1 
inner join generatedAlias1.entitiesB as generatedAlias0 
where ( generatedAlias2.A.status<>:param0 ) and ( generatedAlias2.propertyOne like :param1 ) 
order by generatedAlias2.propertyM desc
```

I got the following exception:

```
    'org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
Invalid path  generatedAlias2.A.status '
```

How can I fix it? I am using Hibernate 4.3.5 as the persistence provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CriteriaQuery query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(A.class);

means that you want to return instances of type `A`. Therefore, your `select` clause must specify query root instead of an instance of `Join` as you did:

1. Define the root of the query because the `join` method can only be applied either to an instance of `Root` or `Join` types:

   ```
   Root<A> root = query.from(A.class);
   ```
2. Define Join (`I need to left join A with B`):

   ```
   Join<A, B> b = root.join("entitiesB", JoinType.LEFT);
   ```
3. Define the `SELECT`clause:

   ```
   query.select(root)
   .distinct(true)
   .where(formWhereClause(filters))
   .orderBy(formOrderByClause());
   ```
4. > How do I form the filter by the status property from A entity

Form it as follows:

```
criteriaBuilder.notEqual(root.get("status"), "SOME_STATUS_VALUE");
```

and if you want to use attributes of `B` as a filter define it, for example, as:

```
criteriaBuilder.equal(b.get("propertyOne"), "SOME_VALUE");
```