# How to search in parent and in the child Collection the same type using CriteriaBuilder and Specification

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have an entity with self mapping like this:

```
@Entity
class Category{
    String categoryName;
    // other fields

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_category_id")
    private Category parentCategory;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentCategory", cascade = {CascadeType.All})
    Set<Category> subcategories;
}
```

I want to search by categoryName in the parent category and in subcategories. I use criteriaBuilder. Is it posiible to make search like this? The first condition I use is search only in parent categories to exclude category duplication(parent and child). I use conditions:

```
Root root = ...
CriteriaBuilder cb = ...
Predicate predicate = cb.isNull(root.get("categoryName")); //after this search will be perfomed only by parent category
Predicate predicate = cb.like(cb.lower(root.get("categoryName")), "category value%"); //search perfomed only in parents
```

I don't now how to get into subcategories list and if in sabcategories this value is exist I want to get parent category with this subcategories.

Database design:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categories (
  category_id BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('categories_category_id_seq'),
  category_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  parent_category_id BIGINT,
  CONSTRAINT categories_pkey PRIMARY KEY (category_id),
  CONSTRAINT parent_category_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (parent_category_id) REFERENCES 
categories (category_id)
);
```

Comment: can you please post design of database?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Use .join() for the subCategories and the parent

[How to use JPA Criteria API in JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980869/how-to-use-jpa-criteria-api-in-join)

You may have to define an alias for the joined table, because the do have the same names.

[Hibernate Criteria Join with 3 Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726396/hibernate-criteria-join-with-3-tables)

[Invalid alias when joining two JPA entities via JPA 2.0 CriteriaBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39213495/invalid-alias-when-joining-two-jpa-entities-via-jpa-2-0-criteriabuilder)